# What do these mean: pupushik and pupushonok?

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения, сленг, идиомы

A man used the first and a woman used the second, to each other. What exactly do they mean? Are they naughty terms of endearment or harmless, cute ones?

:-)

Context: Armenian man and Ukrainian woman from Lviv writing to each other in Latin script Online. I have spelled exactly as they have.

Comment: I think you need to provide some context, but I would say those are very likely endearing nicknames.

Comment: Agree with @Alexander that context is needed. The endearing nickname could be originating from colloquial Armenian word [պուպուշ / pupush](https://hy.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%BA%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%BA%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%B7)

Comment: or maybe these are **пупсик** and **пупсёнок**?

Comment: Without context, they sound like an elaborately and unbearably corny attempt at cutesiness, with something cringey about their very sound.

Comment: an Armenian origin of **pupushik** is traced [here](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/armenian_to_english/general_conversation_greetings_letters/3555602-pupushik.html) and in Google in general including in Cyrillic orthography, but the second word is surely russified with the suffix **-онок**

Comment: @Vitaly I believe you are right, because the users are Armenian man and Ukrainian woman who is trying to fit into the Armenian community. They use Russian to communicate, so I assumed it was Russian, akin to pupichka... diminuitive, but either endearment or naughty. I was unsure. I can see how it could be an Armenian term he taught her.

Answer (score 2):

I think they said `кукушка` (cuckoo) and `кукушонок` (little cuckoo).
The following tongue twister was meant:

> Кукушка кукушонку купила капюшон.
>
> Надел кукушонок капюшон.
>
> Как в капюшоне он смешон.
>
> (The cuckoo bought a hood for the little cuckoo.
>
> The little cuckoo put the hood on.
>
> How funny looks it now.)

Answer (score 2):

`пупсик` is a word in common use — *naughty term of endearment or harmless, cute one*

You can use suffix `-онок` — `пупсёнок`,
It is not really in common use, but every-one still get it. The word has the same meaning. Maybe a little cutier.

Finally, `pupushik` and `pupushonok` — `пупушик` and `пупушонок` — it is not known words for a Russian speaker, but they are similar to `пупсик`, everyone will notice that, and will assume what it is some kind of *naughty terms of endearment or harmless, cute ones*.

Comment: I'd say pupushonok might exist, mutated from kukushonok in the "kuzdra kudlachit bokrenka" way :-D

Comment: I'd guess that both пупушик and пупушонок are different mixes of кукушонок and пушистик.

Comment: While the words `pupushik` and `pupushonok` are unknown to most Russian speakers, searches on Google show that they are used as tags for pictures of cute children.

Comment: The topic starter might mishear the words

Comment: I wrote them here from a photo of the writing made by the original users. So it is correct and in Latin script as they used with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these words are 'russified' forms of a colloquial Armenian word **pupush / պուպուշ.** According to [Armenian Wiktionary](https://hy.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%BA%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%BA%D5%B8%D6%82%D5%B7) it is an adjective meaning *lovely, sweetheart.*

The Russian words *пупушик* and *пупушонок* are nouns that are formed using diminutive suffixes *-ик* and *-онок.* Based on sparse internet usage, these words are used as cute terms of endearment ("pet names") applied to loved ones and children.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a potshot at it

Maybe these are **пупсик** and **пупсёнок**, which are (at least the first one) not uncommon as names of endearment between romantic partners.

Here're translation options for **пупсик** from [Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EF%F3%EF%F1%E8%EA)

> kewpie; kewpie doll; munchkin; baby doll; cutie
>   cutie pie
>   babycakes; pookie

But a picture is worth a 1000 words

[image]
[[image]**ПУПС**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiXmT.png)

Comment: никогда не слышал "potshot" в этом контексте. Как по мне выражение немного странно звучит.) Может, в Америке так говорят, но у нас (Канада), точно нет. Это звучит, как будто Вы хотите оскорбить кого-то или само слово))

Comment: @VCH250 appreciate the feedback, found this expression in a dictionary with some confirmations from web sources, have never heard it though either, i guess ***a shot in the dark*** is more common, what other idioms you'd personally use if i may ask?